# Deleting a particular character from a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a string `"puete"` and I want to delete the last `"e"`, how can I do it?

I have used `del[len(str)-1]` but there is error showing `'str does not support item deletion'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str` objects](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#text-sequence-type-str) don't support item deletion because they're immutable. The closest you can do is to make a new string w/out the last character by [slicing the string](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
In [20]: 'puete'[:-1]
Out[20]: 'puet'
```

Comment: can you elaborate you solution

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, i.e. can't be changed in-place; you *cannot* delete a single character. Instead, create a new string and assign it back to the same name:

```
s = "puete"
s = s[:-1]
```

The slice `[:-1]` means "up to but not including the last character", and will create a new string object with fewer characters.